# I cant make my wireless work on my new version 16.04 for Laptop HP Pavillion dv4

Tags: drivers, 16.04, wireless

```
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at d1010000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at d1000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Expansion ROM at d2600000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI-X: Enable- Count=2 Masked-
    Capabilities: [cc] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 76-00-00-00-ff-ff-00-00
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: That is your ethernet device, not wireless. Please edit your question to add the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Answer (score 0):

Make me understand better.
I suppose your wireless card don't showing the wireless networks near you. 
Try open Terminal and:

```
NetworkManager
```